# Excel VBA to Find any of a lot of characters

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel 2011 for Mac how can I find the next cell with ANY of these characters in it:

ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÈÉÊËèéêëÌÍÎÏìíîïÑñÒÓÔÕÖòóôõöÙÚÛÜùúûüÝýÿ

(One or more of these chars will be embedded in other strings in the cell. e.g. Málaga Desktop)

I'd rerun this manually to find the next cell until no more hits remain.

Comment: Your question is not about programming

Comment: I feel it is about programming.  e.g. it may require something like a Regex string in the Find command of Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on a cell in the column of interest.  Running this macro repeatedly will walk you down the column to find each occurrence of the desired characters:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim s As String, r As Range, rng As Range, N As Long
    Dim v As String, CH As String, i As Long

    s = "ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÈÉÊËèéêëÌÍÎÏìíîïÑñÒÓÔÕÖòóôõöÙÚÛÜùúûüÝýÿ"
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range(ActiveCell, Cells(N, ActiveCell.Column))

    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Text
        If v <> "" Then
            For i = 1 To Len(v)
                CH = Mid(v, i, 1)
                If InStr(s, CH) > 0 Then
                    r.Select
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next r
    MsgBox "NO MORE CHARACTERS FOUND"
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

This version will cover all of UsedRange:

```
Public lastfound As Range

Sub ytrewq()
    Dim s As String, r As Range, rng As Range, start As Boolean
    Dim v As String, CH As String, i As Long, st As String

    s = "ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÈÉÊËèéêëÌÍÎÏìíîïÑñÒÓÔÕÖòóôõöÙÚÛÜùúûüÝýÿ"

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    start = False
    On Error Resume Next
        st = lastfound.Address(0, 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If st = "" Then
        Set lastfound = rng(1)
    End If


    For Each r In rng
        If start Then
            v = r.Text
            If v <> "" Then
                For i = 1 To Len(v)
                    CH = Mid(v, i, 1)
                    If InStr(s, CH) > 0 Then
                        r.Select
                        Set lastfound = Selection
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        End If

        If r.Address(0, 0) = lastfound.Address(0, 0) Then
            start = True
        End If
    Next r
    MsgBox "NO MORE CHARACTERS FOUND"
End Sub
```

**EDIT#2:**

The behaviour of the above is to hang up once the *NOT FOUND* condition is detected.  The following version *(adds a single line of code at the end)* will allow the whole thing to re-start from the beginning:

```
Public lastfound As Range

Sub ytrewq()
    Dim s As String, r As Range, rng As Range, start As Boolean
    Dim v As String, CH As String, i As Long, st As String

    s = "ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÈÉÊËèéêëÌÍÎÏìíîïÑñÒÓÔÕÖòóôõöÙÚÛÜùúûüÝýÿ"

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    start = False
    On Error Resume Next
        st = lastfound.Address(0, 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If st = "" Then
        Set lastfound = rng(1)
    End If


    For Each r In rng
        If start Then
            v = r.Text
            If v <> "" Then
                For i = 1 To Len(v)
                    CH = Mid(v, i, 1)
                    If InStr(s, CH) > 0 Then
                        r.Select
                        Set lastfound = Selection
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        End If

        If r.Address(0, 0) = lastfound.Address(0, 0) Then
            start = True
        End If
    Next r
    MsgBox "NO MORE CHARACTERS FOUND"
    Set lastfound = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Gary -- Thanks for this code. It does work in a column.  Can it be made to operate over the entire Excel worksheet's "non-empty" range rather than just a column? (don't need to ask user for the range -- just automatically find the range with all the non-empty cells and run it over that).

Comment: @s2016  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thanks Gary, appreciate the quick help.

Comment: Now when I run either of the 2 macros above it is only finding 1 instance.  When I rerun the macro it just finds the same 1 instance.

Comment: @s2016  **make sure the DIM for lastfound is above the sub.**

Comment: I'm getting some weird behaviour.  I am trying to use both your macros.  EDIT#1 -- I moved the PUBLIC DIM to the top of the Module.  (Above both your macros).  It then worked once - i.e. I repeatedly ran it and it found the next instance.  But now when I run it finds "no more chars found".  ------- FIRST MACRO (By Column) -- still only find first instance and nothing more.

Comment: @s2016  I think I understand what is happening..........see my upcoming **EDIT#2**

Answer (score 3):

The build in `FIND()` does not support this.

Like `FIND` this UDF returns the position of the first occurrence of any of those chars else `#VALUE!`

Add a VBA module and paste:

```
Public Function ContainsAccented(value As String) As Long
    Const chars As String = "ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÈÉÊËèéêëÌÍÎÏìíîïÑñÒÓÔÕÖòóôõöÙÚÛÜùúûüÝýÿ"
    If value Like "*[" & chars & "]*" Then
        For ContainsAccented = 1 To Len(value)
            If InStr(1, chars, Mid$(value, ContainsAccented, 1)) Then Exit Function
        Next
    End If
    ContainsAccented = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

Then use `=ContainsAccented(A1)`

Comment: Alex K -- Thanks for posting this code.  It does work as you say.  (I am moving forward with Gary's code below which is closer to my OP.) Thanks again.